# Sed replace only in even numbered lines of a file when replace commands are written in a file

Tags: bash, unix, regex, sed

I have all the replace commands in a file (say replace.sed) and i use it with -f flag of sed (sed -f replace.sed InputFile). But now i ran into a condition where i need to apply these replace rules only on even numbered lines of a given input file (i.e only on line no 2,4,6 and so on).I can not put any condition statements in replace.sed file as that is used by another scripts also.

Answer (score 1):

Use process substitution to adapt the `sed` commands in your file on the fly:

```
$ cat replace.sed
s#foo#bar#
```

.

```
$ printf "foo\nfoo\nfoo\nfoo\n" | sed -f replace.sed
bar
bar
bar
bar
```

.

```
$ printf "foo\nfoo\nfoo\nfoo\n" | sed -f <(sed 's#^#2~2#g' replace.sed)
foo
bar
foo
bar
```

Answer (score 1):

```
sed -f <(sed -e 's/.*/2~2{&;}/' replace.sed) InputFile
```

Answer (score 1):

What the other answers are <strike>telling you</strike> trying to tell you
is to use `sed`’s `first~step` address form:

> **Addresses**
>
>   …   
>     
>     The following address types are supported:   …
>   *first*
>   ~
>   *step*
>     Match every
>     *step*
>     ’th line starting with line
>     *first*
>     . 
>       For example,  “
>     `sed -n 1~2p`
>     ” 
>       will print all the odd-numbered lines in the input stream,
>       and the address  “
>     `2~5`
>     ”  will match every fifth line, starting with the second.
>     *first*
>     can be zero; in this case,
>     `sed`
>     operates as if it were equal to
>     *step*
>     . 
>       (This is an extension.)

The obvious solution would be to precede every command in `replace.sed` with `2~2`
(or `0~2`, if it works in your version of `sed`)
to make the commands operate on every other line, starting with the second
(i.e., all the even-numbered lines in the input stream, as you requested). 
But you say that you cannot modify `replace.sed`. 
Well, the next step (as identified, but not explained, by the other answers) is
to create a transient temporary file with the shell’s **Process Substitution** capability,
where `<(command_list)` acts like a file that is the output
of `command_list`. 
If, as your question suggests, `replace.sed`
is just a sequence of simple substitute commands, then

```
sed -f <(sed 's/^/2~2/g' replace.sed)
```

should work.

But this has drawbacks:

- If you have multiple commands per line,
  then the above will affect only the first command on each line.
- If you have commands with numeric addresses (e.g., `42s/Zaphod/Beeblebrox/`),
  they will be converted, e.g., into `2~242…`, with the obvious consequence.
- And if you have commands with non-numeric addresses (e.g., `/windows/s/command/cmd/`)
  the above will fail outright.

If any of these cases apply, you should use the

```
sed -f <(sed -e 's/.*/2~2{&;}/' replace.sed)
```

variation to put all the `sed` commands on each line into a command group.

But even this will fail if `replace.sed` has multi-line commands.

Building on the above ideas, I came up with

```
sed -f <(echo '0~2{'; cat replace.sed; echo '}')
```

which puts the *entire* `replace.sed` file into a command group. 
In my superficial testing,
this seems to address the concerns I raised with the other solutions. 
I wouldn’t be shocked if it has a problem with a very long `replace.sed`,
or with very complex commands.